# Does LLBLGen wrap a recursive save in a transaction by default?

Tags: .net, orm, llblgenpro

When saving an entity with related entities in LLBLGen, will it automatically wrap the DB calls inside a transaction, or could some portion of the save fail while other portions succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive saves are always wrapped in a transaction. Single saves are only wrapped into a transaction if the entity is in a TPE inheritance hierarchy. Otherwise the single INSERT/UPDATE statement isn't wrapped into a transaction as it is already a transaction (atomic unit) on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when saving an Entity and it's related entities, using the recurse flag, it should encapsulate the calls into a single transaction.

Comment: I don't disagree that it should, but do you have any source information that confirms this behavior?